# get an infinite flux from a reactive mongo source

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-webflux, reactive-programming

Out of the box, the `ReactiveMongoTemplate`'s `find()` method will return a `Flux` of data that matches the query.  Once it reaches the end of the query results, it will complete.

I want to keep this `Flux` open so I can continually get new items that match the query as they come in.  I wasn't sure if `Flux.create()` was the right way to go since it would mean creating an infinite loop that just calls `find()` then subscribes to it- calling `sink.next()` for each element.

I saw some examples that use a combination of `.defer` and `.repeat` on here and wondered if that would apply to my use case.  Here is what I am thinking of trying:

```
public Flux<Document> tail(String conversation) {
    final AtomicLong startFrom = new AtomicLong(0L);
    return Flux.defer(() -> reactiveMongoTemplate.find(
                Query.query(
                    Criteria.where("conversation").is(conversation)
                            .and("sequence").gt(startFrom.get()))))
            .doOnNext(d-> { if(d.get("sequence") > startFrom.get()) startFrom.set(item.getSequence()); })
            .repeat();
}
```

In this case the mongo collection holds documents related to "conversations".  I'm trying to stream documents related to a target conversation and provide that `Flux` to a reactive WebSocket or other consumer.

The `defer()` should cause the query to rerun with every `repeat()` interval in theory.  The doOnNext simply keeps track of the highest sequence number it saw and uses that for the next call to `find()`

Not sure if there is a better or safer way of doing this.  I am new to reactive and the old school imperative way of doing this would be to use a poller.

EDIT: Another version that recursively concats the flux with a call to the original function

```
public Flux<Document> tail(String conversation, final AtomicLong startFrom) {
    return Flux.defer(() -> reactiveMongoTemplate.find(
                Query.query(
                    Criteria.where("conversation").is(conversation)
                            .and("sequence").gt(startFrom.get())), org.bson.Document.class))
            .doOnNext(d-> { 
                if(d.get("sequence") > startFrom.get())
                    startFrom.set(d.get("sequence")); 
            })
            .concat(
                Flux.defer(() -> 
                    tail(conversation, startFrom)));
}
```

Comment: You could probably use a recursive `concat(...)` instead

Comment: @IgorArtamonov I edited my question to include what I think the recursive `concat()` would look like.  is that what you had in mind?  you're a legend btw.

Comment: Yes, something like that. I'm not sure this particular code, because it seems it can cause an infinite recursion. Does it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I suggested in the comments, a `concat` maybe a simpler alternative. In this case you could make a *recursive* call, but it's important to call the recursion lazily only when the next step is actually subscribed. For example wrapping it with another `defer`:

```
public Flux<Document> tail(AtomicLong startFrom, String conversation, long start) {
    return Flux.defer(() -> ...main code...)
            .concat(
               Flux.defer(() -> 
                 // here we call itself again
                 tail(new AtomicLong(start), conversation, startLong.get())
               ));
}
```

Comment: Thanks Igor - I think I follow.  I updated the recursion version in my original post a little.  I got a little tripped up on the need for both a long and AtomicLong param.  It was originally there for convenience of the caller.  The purpose was twofold: the allow the original call to skip ahead if it didn't care about older documents, as well as to make sure the next go-around didn't include records from the prior result.  Unless I'm missing something else.

Comment: I didn't get the AtomicLong param actually, and in my example it maybe be used in a wrong way. I just decided to move it inside the _defer_, b/c I though it might be easier to read the code, but that may be not so necessary

Comment: I see.  Yeah the main purpose of the AtomicLong was to keep track of state.  It want to be able to identify the last record returned so that the next call to find() didn't return duplicates.  This relies on the document have an incremental sequence field.  I've been trying to think of a more elegant way.

Comment: Hey Igor - I've been digesting this with some colleagues and also getting started on testing it out.  I have a couple of follow up questions to the answer.  The first (and simpler) questions is that Flux.concat() is static.  Can I assume you meant `concatWith()`?  Alternatively I think it would be equivalent (albiet messy) to do `Flux.concat(Flux.defer( main code ), Flux.defer( recursive call to tail ))`?  And, more importantly, why do you prefer concat() over repeat() in this case?  Are there some drawbacks to repeat()?

Comment: You're right, it should be `contactWith`. Though `Flux.concat` works too. I didn't consider `repeat`, but I think it's a better idea b/c it probably looks easier to understand